# jQuery working locally but not on my server

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

yesterday I put my first website online at [Leaguestrats.com](http://www.leaguestrats.com) and everything seemed fine but others weren't able to access it so I fixed that and someone told me to check i through http://anonymouse.org/ to see if it's working fine and now I see that my dropdown menu isn't working, even though it's working just fine locally.

Here's where I link my files in the head tag

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JS -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas what's causing this? I'm using the dropdown from Bootstrap if that helps

Comment: Dropdown works fine for me...

Comment: I think anonymoose just blocks scripts then ..
Does everything work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Try loading all scripts from `https` instead of mixing `http` and `https`.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)'s why you shouldn't mix both.

Comment: Okay, thank you i'll have to remember that for in the future

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing your script protocol to dynamically load the resources under the current protocol (e.g. `https` if your site is under an SSL or `http` if not).

For example:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JS -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try loading bootstrap.min.js AFTER you are loading jQuery. Bootstrap needs jQuery as a dependency.

From Bootstrap's docs...
"jQuery required
Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included"

Comment: If I load JS before loading jQuery it gives me an error saying BS requires jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I cannot acces the proxy you linked, but maybe the browser or the proxy does not load the files correctly, i wouldnt trust a proxy as a reliable "other users experience" because of all the tricks it might use.

Check with the web developer tools (usually F12) in your browser if the files are loaded, theres probably a "newtwork" tab that shows this